# Asking about webClient in Windowsphone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, webclient

I'm trying to create a simple app for my phone that can get data from a website and save to the phone. After I looked for, I knew I have to use webClient for this app. When I code I have a problem that set value for a property in a class.

```
class data
{
    public string temp = "";
    public void getContent(string url)
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) => { /*my problem is right here*/};
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
    }
}
```

For example: e.result = "this is a book" so how can I set "**e.result**" for "**temp**"?

Answer (score 1):

just replace

```
client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) => { /*my problem is right here*/};
```

with

```
client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) => { 
  temp = e.Result;
};
```